# Meu aplicativo no android studio está fechando, ao consumir webservice

Tags: php, java, android, web-service, android-studio

Estou com um problema em minha aplicação, ao consumir um serviço web service, o aplicativo está fechando.

A ideia de meu aplicativo é eu consumir este web service para validar meu login, e retornando uma mensagem aprovando ou não, não tenho habilidade com Android, sou recente na programação do mesmo por isso não sei se faço algo correto. Gostaria que me ajudassem nesta etapa do projeto.

Este código refere ao MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.hotsystems.hs_celulas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String asw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hs_cell);

        //Chamar os objetos
        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TXT_EMAIL_LOGIN);
        final EditText senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TXT_SENHA_LOGIN);
        final EditText cod_igrej = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.COD_IGREJ_LOGIN);
        Button entrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTN_ENTRA_APLIC);
        Button sair = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTN_SAIRX_APLIC);

        entrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Usuario usr = new Usuario();

                String json = generateJson(usr);
                String result = callServer("send-json", json);

                if(result.equals("3")){
                    Log.i("MainActivity", result);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Código da igreja inesistente, por favor escreva um código válido." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (result.equals("2")){
                    Log.i("MainActivity", result);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Senha incorreto, por favor escreva uma senha válida." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (result.equals("1")){
                    Log.i("MainActivity", result);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "E-mail incorreto, por favor escreva um email válido." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                }

            }
        });

        sair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public String generateJson(Usuario usr){
        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TXT_EMAIL_LOGIN);
        final EditText senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TXT_SENHA_LOGIN);
        final EditText cod_igrej = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.COD_IGREJ_LOGIN);

        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

        String strEmail = email.getText().toString();
        String strSenha = senha.getText().toString();
        String strCod = cod_igrej.getText().toString();

        try{
            jo.put("email", strEmail);
            jo.put("senha", strSenha);
            jo.put("cod_igrej", strCod);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return(jo.toString());
    }

    public Usuario degenerateJson(String data){
        Usuario usr = new Usuario();

        try{
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

            usr.setEmail(jo.getString("email"));
            usr.setEmail(jo.getString("senha"));
            usr.setEmail(jo.getString("cod_igrej"));

            /*jo.put("email", Usuario.getEmail());
            jo.put("senha", Usuario.getSenha() );
            jo.put("cod_igrej", Usuario.getCod());*/


        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return(usr);
    }

    private String callServer(final String method, final String data){

        new Thread(){

            public void run(){
                asw = Connection.getSetDataWeb("http://192.168.1.20/renan/process.php", method, data);

                if (data.isEmpty()){
                    degenerateJson(asw);
                }
            }
        }.start();
        return asw;
    }

}
```

Também gostaria que me dissessem se o método como eu chamo a próxima tela após o login está implementada da melhor forma. A baixo segue meu servidor web service.

```
<?php
require_once('Usuario.php');
include('conexao.php');


if(strcmp('send-json', $_POST['method']) == 0)
{ // SEND

    $Usuario = utf8_encode($_POST['json']);
    $Usuario = json_decode($Usuario);

    $email = $Usuario->email;
    $senha = $Usuario->senha;
    $cod_igrej = $Usuario->cod_igrej;



    $sql = "SELECT COD_IDENT_IGREJ, TXT_NOMEX_IGREJ, FLG_STATU_IGREJ FROM tbl_IGREJAS WHERE COD_IDENT_IGREJ = '".$cod_igrej."'";
    $sql2 = "SELECT COD_IDENT_USUAR, TXT_EMAIL_LOGIN, TXT_SENHA_LOGIN FROM tbl_USUARIOS WHERE TXT_EMAIL_LOGIN = '".$email."'";

    $resultado = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($resultado) == 0) 
    {
            $val= '003';
    }else
    {
            $resultado = mysql_query($sql2);
            if (mysql_num_rows($resultado) == 0 ) 
            {
                $val='001';
            }else 
            {
                $usuario = mysql_fetch_object($resultado);
                if ($senha == $usuario->TXT_SENHA_LOGIN) {
                    $val='000';
                }else{
                    $val= '002';
                }
            }
    }





    switch ($val) 
    {
        case '001':
        /*E-mail incorreto, por favor escreva um email válido.*/
            echo '1';
            break;

        case '002':
        /*Senha incorreta, por favor escreva uma senha válido.*/
            echo '2';
            break;

        case '003':
        /*Codigo da igreja inesistente, por favor escreva um codigo válido.*/
            echo '3';
            break;


        default:
        /*Login efetuado com sucesso*/
            echo '0';
            break;
    };

}


else if(strcmp('get-json', $_POST['method']) == 0)
{ // GET
    $Usuario = new Usuario();
    $Usuario->setEmail(utf8_encode('Renan'));
    $Usuario->setSenha('12345');
    $Usuario->setCod('001');


    echo json_encode($Usuario->getDataJSON());
}
```

?>

O erro básico está aqui o

```
switch (result){
                case "3":
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Código da igreja inesistente, por favor escreva um código válido." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Senha incorreto, por favor escreva uma senha válida." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "1":
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "E-mail incorreto, por favor escreva um email válido." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(it);
            }
```

Eu preciso comparar com a resposta vindo do webservice, porem ai que esta dando a falha. O Logcat é:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.hotsystems.hs_celulas.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no log pra ver a mensagem de erro?

Comment: 08:24:46 Gradle build finished in 16s 980ms
08:39:57 Gradle build finished with 5 error(s) in 9s 72ms
09:41:27 Gradle build finished in 2s 884ms

Comment: Acredito que o log solicitado é o que aparece no *logcat*, onde informa com mais detalhes o erro ocorrido.

Comment: Na verdade o erro memso ta aqui o:

Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(it);
Quando eu chamo a outra tela, qual metodo correto de fazer isto ?

Comment: Coloque o código da classe **Home** também. O erro deve estar nela.

Comment: Olha, sem saber qual o *stack trace* fica realmente complicado adivinhar qual o erro, por isso é importante informar o que está vindo no *logcat*.

Comment: a classe Home está com o codigo Hello Wold.

Comment: O `NullPointerException` acontece porque a sua variável `result` é nula no momento que você realiza as suas condições já que o método `callServer` é executado em outra *thread*.

Comment: como devo corrigir isto ?

Comment: Muito Obrigado Paulo Rodrigues, conseguir resolver o problema ! Boa tarde.

Answer (score 0):

Para requisições sugiro utilizar o [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) ou [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html), atualmente o mais rápido é o RetroFit, porém o volley é mais fácil.